# "Quoting within quoting" question for professed bash affectionate

Tags: bash, quoting

Out of sheer curiosity I would like to know how this quoting dilemma can be fixed.
I already solved the issue by circumnavigating it (I added [vcodec!*=av01] to the -f argument and simply removed the --exec part entirely). Otherwise it **only worked, when there were no spaces or minus signs** in the --exec argument.
The culprit line is the last and the issue is at the end with the --exec argument. You can ignore the rest.

Thanks for your help on the road to enlightenment! ;-)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

trap "exit" INT

avtomp4conv () {
  # tests if the given file (in argument) is an AV1 media and if so, converts it to mp4
  echo "${1}"
  if ($( ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "${1}" | grep -i av > /dev/null )); then
    echo "$1 bad codec"
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -stats -i "${1}" -movflags faststart -preset ultrafast "${1%.mp4}_fixed.mp4" && mv "${1}" bogus/ && mv -n "${1%.mp4}_fixed.mp4" "${1}"
  fi
}

# ... lotsa other stuff ...

export -f avtomp4conv
cat links.txt | parallel -u -I % --retries 3 --max-args 1 --jobs 4 python3 `which youtube-dl` -c -f "'bestvideo[height<=720][ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/mp4'" --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args "'-x 4 -s 4'" --exec \'bash -c \"export -f avtomp4conv\;avtomp4conv \{\}\"\' %
```

Comment: `parallel` adds a lot of generally-undesirable behavior (its author is here, and will probably dispute that, but I'd suggest reading https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parallel/2015-05/msg00005.html for background; there's no dispute as to the behavior, but lots of room for dispute as to whether that behavior is desirable). I wouldn't pose this as a bash question -- I would pose it as a parallel question, since that's where the otherwise-unnecessary complexity is injected.

Comment: (Have you considered using `xargs -P` instead?)

Comment: BTW, why the subshell? `if ($(...) >/dev/null); then` would be much better writtes as `if ...; then`; it avoids the subshell overhead. Also, note that if you add the `-q` argument to `grep` it won't emit stdout, and can short-circuit to exit as soon as its result is knowable.

Comment: _In general_, though: I'd consider it obligatory for any well-structured alternative to this code to not contain _any_ code manually quoted to be injected into other code at all. When such a thing is _absolutely necessary_ bash provides automated ways to do it (see `printf '%q ' "${array[@]}"` and/or `"${var@Q}"`), but it's generally possible (and preferable) to avoid using any constructs or tools that would otherwise require the practice in the first place.

Comment: I come from C++. Whenever I write a shell-script, I get an itch and stop half way. ;-) Thank you for that impressive information. If I recall it correctly, I picked "parallel" for the better output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another function to save you from the double indirection in a single command (`parallel` executes `youtube-dl` that executes `avtomp4conv`). GNU `parallel` uses your current shell to execute its commands, so no need for `bash -c` here.

```
avtomp4conv () {
   ...
}
ytdl() {
   youtube-dl ... --exec "bash -c 'avtomp4conv \"$0\"' {}"
}
export -f avtomp4conv ytdl
< links.txt parallel ... ytdl
```

Without the function `ytdl` you could try the following. But why bother with these nested quotes?

```
< links.txt parallel ... -I insteadOf{} \
"youtube-dl ... --exec \"bash -c 'avtomp4conv \\\"\$0\\\"' {}\""
```

Comment: Oh yes, put that in a function as well. I completely forgot about that possibility. Thank you. I'm gonna try out the quoting stuff, when I can find time (gotta do some - physical - repairs).